# I have a mongod process but i did not install mongodb, what could this be?

Tags: centos, ssh, mongodb

when I do a `top` I could see `mongod` in the top consumers:

[image: Gaga ramama]

But I do not have `mongodb` installed:

[image: Gaga oohlala]

How do I remove `mongod`? I know I could easily do a `kill 571` but it's not neat. Could this be a virus or something.

Comment: It could be all sorts of things.  You'll need to investigate further to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be anything.

Run 'which mongod' and 'which mongo' (both as you and root) to see if they're in either's PATH.

You can try to open them in a text editor to see if they're scripts, or 'strings' on a binary file.

But honestly the simplest answer is probably the most likely; someone installed MongoDB.  Check your /etc/init.d (or the Red Hat equivalent) for it's startup scripts.  Check the apt/yum config to see if non-linux-distro repositories have been added.  (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian-or-ubuntu-linux/)

Many people download MongoDB from 10gen or use their hosted apt and yum repos because the distros are difficult to work with and lag behind releases.

If you don't want it installed, kill the process and remove it.

Comment: better still: `updatedb; locate mongod`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **yum** to identify it:

```
# yum whatprovides "*/bin/mongod"
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, rhnplugin, security
mongodb-server-1.6.4-1.el5.i386 : MongoDB server, sharding server and support
                                : scripts
Repo        : EPEL-i386
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/mongod
```

Therefore, your machine probably has mongodb-server installed. So, to be rid of mongod, you would need to use **yum** to remove the mongodb-server package like so:

```
# yum remove mongodb-server
```

Comment: As long as another package isn't using it.  For example, katello uses mongodb, so if you are running katello, removing mongodb will try to remove katello also. `rpm -q --whatrequires mongodb-server` will show you what depends on it.

Comment: Running  yum remove  displays all dependenci

Comment: Running  yum remove  displays all dependencies and prompts you whether you actually want to to remove the packages and those packages that depend on that package.  So there is no danger in running the command.